# How to convert the string representation of a Terraform set of strings to a slice of strings

Tags: go, slice, terratest

I've a terratest where I get an output from terraform like so `s := "[a b]"`. The terraform output's `value = toset([resource.name])`, it's a set of strings.

Apparently `fmt.Printf("%T", s)` returns **string**. I need to iterate to perform further validation.

I tried the below approach but errors!

```
var v interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &v); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

My current implementation to convert to a slice is:

```
s := "[a b]"
s1 := strings.Fields(strings.Trim(s, "[]"))
for _, v:= range s1 {
    fmt.Println("v -> " + v)
}
```

Looking for suggestions to current approach or alternative ways to convert to arr/slice that I should be considering. Appreciate any inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your current implementation seems just fine.

You can't use JSON unmarshaling because JSON strings must be enclosed in double quotes `"`.

Instead [`strings.Fields`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Fields) does just that, it splits a string on one or more characters that match `unicode.IsSpace`, which is `\t`, `\n`, `\v`. `\f`, `\r` and  .

Moeover this works also if terraform sends an empty set as `[]`, as stated in the documentation:

> returning [...] an empty slice if s contains only white space.

...which includes the case of `s` being empty `""` altogether.

In case you need additional control over this, you can use [`strings.FieldsFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#FieldsFunc), which accepts a function of type `func(rune) bool` so you can determine yourself what constitutes a "space". But since your input string comes from terraform, I guess it's going to be well-behaved enough.

There may be third-party packages that already implement this functionality, but unless your program already imports them, I think the native solution based on the standard lib is always preferrable.

---

`unicode.IsSpace` actually includes also the higher runes `0x85` and `0xA0`, in which case `strings.Fields` calls `FieldsFunc(s, unicode.IsSpace)`

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    src := "[a b]"
    dst := strings.Split(src[1:len(src)-1], " ")
    fmt.Println(dst)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KVY4r_8RWv6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Eric Lau the problem I faced with ```strings.Split``` is that for an empty output from terraform ```src := []``` the slice returns ```len(dst)``` as 1. I really donno why, but would love to learn the rationale behind it! Folks pls help me understand this behavior..
https://play.golang.org/p/lMRV-_Qy1wk

Comment: @codecorrect that's how [`strings.Split`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split) works. If there's no split happening, it returns a slice with the original string as only elem.